# IndexError: string index out of range for python

Tags: python, string

For the line7 it mentioned that I am facing an error. What should I do?
There is some conditions in the question:
if character is alpha,
add character to word and
non-alpha detected (space, punctuation, digit,...) defines the end of a word and goes to else.
For else:
check if word is greater than "g" alphabetically, if it is: print word and 
set word = empty string,
or else: 
set word = empty string and build the next word

```
phrase = input('enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ')
word = ""
for letter in phrase:
    if letter.isalpha() == True:
        word = word + letter
    else:
        if word[0] > "g":
            print (word.upper() + '\n')
            word = ""
        else:
            word = ""
print (word)
```

Comment: Line 9 appears to be `word = ""`. I highly doubt that's the line giving you that error message.

Comment: The line where you use a string index appears to be `if word[0] > "g":`. I can imagine many ways in which `word` has zero characters in it (like if the first character of the input is non-alpha).

Comment: Post your traceback please.

Comment: I am sorry it should be line7

Comment: You're initializing `word=""` (a zero-length string) . There would be some condition when `phrase[0]` (i.e., the first `letter` is non-alpha, which will raise this error because you can't subscript an empty string.

Comment: perhaps try simply: `if word and word[0] > "g":`

Comment: I tried but it does not respond properly based on my condition

Comment: Can you please provide some input output ? I mean what you input and what you expected for output?

Comment: Input: Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart

Comment: Output (in seperate line): WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART

Answer (score 0):

This code will show your expected answer what you ask in comment section.

```
phrase = input('enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words: ')
word_list = phrase.split(' ')
ans=''
for word in word_list:
    if word[0].lower() > 'g':
        ans+=word.upper()+' '

print(ans)
```

And For the line 7 on your code you always take first letter of your input. That's why it doesn't work.